# Java Servlet: Specify start page wih @WebServlet annotation

Tags: xml, servlets

I work with Eclipse Java EE, I have tomcat 7.xx server and a Java Servlet. I need to specify in the Java Servlet as startpage "WebContent/mypage.html".

How can I do that with the @WebServlet annotation?

This is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/ricerca.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <display-name>Searcher</display-name>
    <description>
        Searcher!
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Searcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.irlab.Searcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Searcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Searcher</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My contex root is: /localhost:8181/Searcher3/

Ok one solution is this: @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Searcher"}) dnd in the doGet method i write:
    request.getRequestDispatcher("ricerca.htm").forward(request,response);

But why web.xml don't work? i need to add something to the Eclipse Project configuration?

Comment: Your web.xml doesn't work because it's not in the right format. See some templates [here](http://dominikdorn.com/2010/03/web-xml-web-fragment-xml-2-3-2-4-2-5-3-0/). Don't reinvent the wheel with a custom `@WebServlet`. Use the utilities that already exist.

Comment: I have update the web.xml but it still does not work..

Comment: Edit your question with the updates you did, please.

Comment: Yes i have just edit now, without @WebServlet i have a 404 error.

Comment: Your file is called `ricerca.htm` or `ricerca.html` or `mypage.html`? Use the right name.

Comment: ricerca.htm is the right name.

Comment: I tried exactly what you have in `web.xml` and the file `ricerca.htm` directly under `/WebContent` and it works.

Comment: Oh now work, it's my fault i write "http://localhost:8181/Searcher3/Searcher" and i go directly to servlet, but if i write "http://localhost:8181/Searcher3/" now go to welcome page. Tanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I maybe should've been more clear about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do that with the @WebServlet annotation ?

`index.html` is one of the default welcome page. You can call Servlet as welcome-page using `@WebServlet` annotation. You need to  mapped your Servlet  `urlPatterns` as `/index.html`. Than at `doGet(..)` method you can forward to `mypage.html` using `RequestDispatcher.forward(..)`.

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/index.html"})
 public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

        throws ServletException, IOException {
       // forward to mypage.html
       request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.html").forward(request,response);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Neptune, For Java EE 6, web.xml is optional. You don't need web.xml.

Comment: Fine, this works. But why i can't put "mypage.tm" in the urlPatterns directly ?

Comment: @Neptune, You can do that, than your URL should like: `http://localhost:8080/AppName/mypage.html`. If you mapped like `index.html` than `http://localhost:8080/AppName/` is enough.

Comment: Now i have a problem, i can find "mypage.html" but i can't find MyApp.
If i go to: 
http://localhost:8181/Searcher3/ i look mypage.htm
but if go to:
http://localhost:8181/Searcher3/Searcher  i have a 404 erro,

Comment: Ok one solution is this:
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Searcher"})

And in the doGet method i write
request.getRequestDispatcher("ricerca.htm").forward(request,response);

But why web.xml don't work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom `Servlet` for that. Just add

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>mypage.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

element to your `web.xml`. [This is documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/webapp005.htm).

Comment: I've done this but don't work. I have add the web.xml in WebContent/WEB-INF folder, then i have run the Eclipse project but don't work.

Comment: @Neptune What do you mean by _don't work_? Do you get a 404? The application doesn't start up? What request are you making that you would expect to work?

Comment: Yes i get a "HTTP Status 404", does not load the html page.

Comment: I think reason you get 404 is your use *.html for servlet mapping so when you request mypage.html, servlet container can't find any servlet for that mapping so it return 404. Go with solution of @Masud.

Comment: @Neptune If you have the `welcome-file` declaration and your file is in `webcontent/mypage.html` and try to access `your-host:your-port/your-context-root`, that page should be loaded. Can you edit your question with your full `web.xml` and your context root?